# Handling multiple exceptions in Python

Tags: python, exception

I want to handle different exceptions in such way that there will be common handling for any exception **and** additional specific handling for `subprocess.CalledProcessError`. Like this:

```
try:
    check_output(shlex.split(rsync_cmd))
except CalledProcessException as e:
    # do some stuff
    # do common exception handling
except Exception as e:
    # do the same common handling
```

I don't want to duplicate code so currently I end up with this code:

```
try:
    check_output(shlex.split(rsync_cmd))
except Exception as e:
    if isinstance(e, CalledProcessError) and e.returncode == 24:
        # do some stuff
    # do common handling
```

What's the best practice to run specific code for one exception *and* to run common code for all exceptions at the same time?

Comment: But I don't want to run exactly the same code for both Exceptions. I want to handle it in a different way with one common part. It is a different case.

Answer (score 3):

You *could* use nested `try:...except` blocks. I don't think it's a satisfactory solution, but here's a simple example.

```
for i in (1, 0, 'z'):
    try:
        try:
            print(i, end=' ')
            x = 1 / i
            print(x)
        except TypeError as e:
            print(e)
            raise
        except ZeroDivisionError as e:
            print(e)
            raise
    except (TypeError, ZeroDivisionError) as e:
        print('Common stuff', e)
```

**output**

```
1 1.0
0 float division
Common stuff float division
z unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'
Common stuff unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'
```

Tested on Python 2.6.6, with `from __future__ import print_function, division`

Answer (score 1):

You may check error not only against class, but also a tuple of classes. In each branch you may check specific properties.

```
    try:
           n=0/0
    except (IOError, ImportError) as e:
         print(1)
    except (NameError) as e:
         print(2)

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
         n=0/0
    ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to have a common code for handling both exceptions with additional code for the first one. This is a different case.

Comment: What if move to a function common case and call it whenever need?

Comment: I already have a function `remove_key()` to call it in `except:` block, but I would like to avoid duplicate function calls.
I want to know if there is a better solution than checking exception class like I do now.

Comment: I do not see any solution which would be much better readable. So-so.

Answer (score 1):

Use inheritance in your exceptions.

```
class GeneralException(Exception)
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)

class SpecificException(GeneralException)
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        super(SpecificException, self).__init__()
    def __str__(self):
        super(SpecificException, self).__str__()
        return repr(self.value)
```

Base logic is, you trigger `SpecificException`s and they all `super` call `GeneralException` to execure related operations

Comment: That is really great for custom exceptions, but this is not my case. Wrapping `CalledProcessError` and `Exception` in my own classes is a bit overkill.

Comment: If you avoid Wrapping, then using simple two-step execption handling is the only solution. try to catch `CalledProcessError`, otherwise, catch any other exception

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that handles the common operations. That's what functions are for.

```
def common_exception_handling(e):
    # do stuff with e
    return  # possibly something

# ...

try:
    check_output(shlex.split(rsync_cmd))
except CalledProcessException as e:
    # do some stuff
    common_exception_handling(e)
except Exception as e:
    common_exception_handling(e)
```

Comment: I already have a function, but I would like to avoid duplication of code, even if it is a single line (personal taste). Thanks anyway!

Comment: Maybe you're right ;) But I'm seeking for a best practice, not for a solution (I already have one).

Comment: Functions are a best practice.

Comment: @Gevial there is no other "best practice" for this case.